# Android studio if statement condition met but program won't enter it

Tags: java, android, string-comparison

So I'm trying to implement a simple class in android studio that takes user input in the form of a spinner and changes the colour of the text accordingly. However, even though the condition has been met, as can be seen by the debugging line, the program will not execute the contents of the if statement.
[debugging line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdBPa.png)

```
'import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Colour extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tv;
Spinner mySpinner;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_colour);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String messageText = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.message);
    tv.setText(messageText);
    mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.colours,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new     AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position)+ " selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

}

public void change(View v){

    String text = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if(text == "Red"){
        tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
    if(text == "Blue"){
        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
    if(text == "Green"){
        tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
}'


 '<TextView
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/message" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/colours"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/spinner" />

<Button
    android:text="HOME"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="home"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="52dp" />

<Button
    android:text="changeColour"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginBottom="101dp"
    android:onClick="change" />'
```

Answer (score 0):

answer would be

`if(text.equals("Red"))` etc

because a text is an object of type String it is not a primitive type

primitive type can be compared using == but not a reference type